# Automatic binding of Windows 8 account with Live ID

Tags: group-policy, scripting, windows-server-2012, windows-8

Is it possible to do automatic binding of Windows 8 account with Live ID thru GPO, scripts, or some sort automated way that will basically do it for everyone in domain. There is an assumption that each Live ID will correspond to their primary Exchange email address in domain.